# RichTextBox doesn't update caret position correctly

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, richtextbox, caret

I have a handler consuming the keyDown event of a WinForms RTB, that has the following code:

```
GetTextAtLoc(RTB->SelectionStart); // selects some text at the caret's position
RTB->SelectedText = "SomeOfMyOwn";
GetTextAtLoc(RTB->SelectionStart); // selects the replacement string
RTB->SelectionStart += RTB->SelectionLength - 1;
```

While this code seems to do its job (SelectionStart/Length properties are updated correctly), the caret doesn't move to the end of the new string - It says right where it was at the time of GetTextAtLoc's first call. Redrawing the textbox doesn't seem to have any effect either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have fixed itself. Dunno what brought about the change, unfortunately. Closing this thread.

Answer (score -1):

You did not specify the new length (and is therefor: 1-1=0). Try something like:

SelectionStart += (length("SomeOfMyOwn"))

Comment: Actually, I did. The second GetTextAtLoc call selects "SomeOfMyOwn" and the subsequent SelectionLength query gets the length of the above literal.

Comment: RTB can be a bit "shady" at times with selections;
Have you tried the Select method using Select(SelectionStart, SelecitonLength)